# Sticky header for table

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a sticky header for table on user scroll. I wrote it and it works, but looks like width of the table elements doesn't work as expected.

https://jsfiddle.net/fj8rtq0g/5/

My JS code is here:

```
window.onload = function() {
  elementsHead = document.querySelectorAll("#result_list thead tr th");
  elementsHead[0].width = document.querySelector("#result_list tbody tr:first-child th").offsetWidth;

  elementsFirstRowBody = document.querySelectorAll("#result_list tbody tr:first-child td");

  for (i = 0; i < elementsHead.length; i++) {
    if (i >= 1) {
      elementsHead[i].width = elementsFirstRowBody[i-1].offsetWidth;
    }
  }

}

window.onscroll = function() {
  addSticky();
};

function addSticky() {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("result_list");
  var sticky = navbar.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (sticky < 0) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

My css code is here:

```
.sticky thead tr {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: red;
}
```

Can someone suggest how to fix this problem? I am using pure javascript.

Comment: Why cant u use position:sticky for header?

Comment: @GautamNaik I tried, but the columns in head are not aligned with columns in body.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution using position sticky
I applied position:sticky to all `th` of the `thead`

Also I removed the javascript code responsible for sizing the columns, but retained the function, that adds color to the `tr`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  /*  elementsHead = document.querySelectorAll("#result_list thead tr th");
   elementsHead[0].width = document.querySelector("#result_list tbody tr:first-child th").offsetWidth;
   
   elementsFirstRowBody = document.querySelectorAll("#result_list tbody tr:first-child td");
   
   for (i = 0; i < elementsHead.length; i++) {
     if (i >= 1) {
       elementsHead[i].width = elementsFirstRowBody[i-1].offsetWidth;
     }
   }
    */
}

window.onscroll = function() {
  addSticky();
};

function addSticky() {
  var navbar = document.getElementById("result_list");
  var sticky = navbar.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  if (sticky < 0) {
    navbar.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

```css
.sticky thead tr th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<table id="result_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Title
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 1
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 2
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 3
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 4
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 5
      </th>
      <th>
        Title 6
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Demo
      </th>
      <td>
        Demo 1
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 2
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 3
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 4
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 5
      </td>
      <td>
        Demo 6
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the "tr" to top: 0 and left: 0 width: 100% and add padding for spacing 20px.

```
.sticky thead tr {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    background: red;
}
```

this will do the trick.

Comment: It works, but the head columns are not aligned with body columns:

https://jsfiddle.net/uj8gkn35/

See where `Title 6` column is. And where `Demo 6` is. I can't understand why this doesn't work.

Comment: Try this Boban: https://jsfiddle.net/Lk0479ft/ keep in mind you can never perfectly align NON position fixed items this because of the browser width, size of the table, content width etc.